# How can i implement join in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I was searching in the web for a full working code for joining 2 files with some matching keys, but i can not find a good one. Can anybody share a full working code for join in hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole chapter on joins in [MapReduce Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025122.do). If you don't have a copy of the book available, the patterns are documented in [this SlideShare presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/zhengwenshen/20130201-mapreduce-design-patterns) (check out slide 65). You can check out some [code examples on github](https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/tree/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch5). (disclaimer: I'm the author of this material)

There are a number of ways to do joins and understanding which one to pick is important for performance.

Comment: Definitely a recommended book but IMVHO, you could indicate that you are a co-author of the book! :)

Comment: @Chiron I actually typically am good about adding the disclaimer. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score -1):

Also check [Data-Intensive Text Processing with MapReduce](http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/). Algorithms and psuedo code are present in the paper, which can be implemented in any language.